# Foreach, wait each iteration until receiving response (making js synchronous)

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, es6-promise

I have a foreach loop and I am iterating through elements. For each element, I am saving it to database using ajax. However, I want each iteration to wait until the previous one is saved into database and received response.

Let me give you a simplified example:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
   let elements = $('.checkboxes:checked');

   elements.forEach(function(i, el) {
      let id = $(el).data('id');

      saveToDatabase(id);
      // I want it to pause here until it receives a response from other function 
      // before going to the next iteration..
   })

})   


function saveToDatabase(id) {
   axios.get('/save-to-db/' + id)
       .then(response => {
           return true;
       }).catch(err => {
           return false;
   });
}
```

I want elements forEach to move to the next iteration after getting a 'return' from `saveToDatabase` function.

(by the way, I know this example is overly simplified and makes no-sense in real life as I can save ids to database in bulk, however I just want to understand how to handle such case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `saveToDatabase(id)` as async function, and in this example use `await`.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

EDIT:
Also, return promise from `saveToDabase` function.

Implementation of saveToDatabase function:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
   let elements = $('.checkboxes:checked');

   for (let element of elements) {
       await saveToDatabase(id);
   }
}) 

async function saveToDatabase(id) {
   return axios.get('/save-to-db/' + id)
       .then(response => {
           return true;
       }).catch(err => {
           return false;
   });
}
```

Also, I forgot:
function in which you use await, needs to have async in front of it too.

Comment: I made it work with this approach and `await saveToDatabase(id)` while calling the function

Comment: Answer from Kevin Pastor IMO also should work. Please, if you made it work, mark any of our answers as correct (correct ones :) ), and edit your main post with solution, so others with similar case, can find it. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Since `forEach` uses a callback function, it is a bit hard to keep using it to synchronise calls. Instead, I think using a simple `for` loop will work.

```
$('#myBtn').click(async () => {
    let elements = $('.checkboxes:checked');
    for (let element of elements) {
        let id = $(element).data('id');
        await saveToDatabase(id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to make requests wait one another. The simplest for you is to save reference for latest request-promise to call next one when previous resolved (inside `then` function).

```
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
   let elements = $('.checkboxes:checked');
   let previousCall = Promise.resolve();

   elements.forEach(function(i, el) {
      let id = $(el).data('id');

      previousCall = previousCall.then(() => saveToDatabase(id));
      // I want it to pause here until it receives a response from other function
      // before going to the next iteration..
   })

})   


function saveToDatabase(id) {
   return axios.get('/save-to-db/' + id)
       .then(response => {
           return true;
       }).catch(err => {
           return false;
   });
}
```

Comment: This approach seems pretty nice however I couldn't make it work. `previousCall = previousCall.then(() => saveToDatabase(id));` doesn't make it wait at all. (I debugged adding a `throw new Error()` to see and it does go to the next iteration :(

Comment: Did you add `return` before `axios.get`? `saveToDatabase` function should return promise, then it should be chained.